# Group by - Overriding default behaviour of deciding row under each group in result

Tags: mysql, overriding, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

Extending further from this question [Query to find top rated article in each category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293930/sql-find-top-rated-article-in-each-category) -

Consider the same table -

```
id | category_id | rating
---+-------------+-------
 1 |           1 |     10
 2 |           1 |      8
 3 |           2 |      7
 4 |           3 |      5
 5 |           3 |      2
 6 |           3 |      6
```

There is a table articles, with fields id, rating (an integer from 1-10), and category_id (an integer representing to which category it belongs). And if I have the same goal to get the top rated articles in each query (this should be the result):-

**Desired Result**

```
id | category_id | rating
---+-------------+-------
 1 |           1 |     10
 3 |           2 |      7
 6 |           3 |      6
```

**Extension of original question**
But, running the following query -

```
SELECT id, category_id, max( rating ) AS max_rating 
FROM `articles`
GROUP BY category_id
```

results into the following where everything, except the `id` field, is as desired. I know how to do this with a subquery - as answered in the same question - [Using subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293930/sql-find-top-rated-article-in-each-category).

```
id  category_id     max_rating
1    1                10
3    2                7
4    3                6
```

**In generic terms**
Excluding the grouped column (`category_id`) and the evaluated columns (columns returning results of aggregate function like `SUM()`, `MAX()` etc. - in this case `max_rating`), the values returned in the other fields are simply the first row under every grouped result set (grouped by `category_id` in this case). E.g. the record with `id` =1 is the first one in the table under `category_id` 1 (`id` 1 and 2 under `category_id` 1) so it is returned.

I am just wondering is it not possible to somehow overcome this default behavior to return rows based on conditions? If mysql can perform calculation for every grouped result set (does `MAX()` counting etc) then why can't it return the row corresponding to the maximum rating.  Is it not possible to do this in a single query without a subquery? This looks to me like a frequent requirement.

**Update**
I could not figure out what I want from Naktibalda's solution too. And just to mention again, I know how to do this using a subquery, as again answered by OMG Ponies.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT x.id,
       x.category_id,
       x.rating
  FROM YOUR_TABLE x
  JOIN (SELECT t.category_id,
               MAX(t.rating) AS max_rating
          FROM YOUR_TABLE t
      GROUP BY t.category_id) y ON y.category_id = x.category_id
                               AND y.max_rating = x.rating
```